# Google Force Adding 'Site name : ' on Search Result

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

Can Anyone Help Me to Remove `Sitename:` from google Search results.

This is my real title name `<title>Web Design & Web Development | Ixeun Software Solutions | Batticaloa</title>` but google adds `iXeun: Web Design & Web Development | Ixeun Software Solutions | Batticaloa` from search results this is little bit confusing for me.

Please Search for `site:ixeun.com` on google so you will find my home page link `root` shows like above.

Comment: Google created unique title because your title is not user friendly. Keyword | Keyword | Keyword - People from 90 do that for SEO.

Comment: so can you answer my question by proper way to title website ? Please

Comment: IDK how to make great title for your website but the title return by Google is looking great. Thousand of pages have same title "Web Design & Web Development service", so they have to change title in order to provide great UX. Do you personally like if google return same title("Hotels in Batticaloa " ) for top 10 results?

Comment: Nope But your answer makes sense :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this answer: [Site URL being displayed before TITLE on SERP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/site-url-being-displayed-before-title-on-serp/78025#78025)

> This is a well known effect for those who experiment with using the
>   pipe character (|) in title tag. I mention it here in an update: Pipes
>   or colons in HTML title tags? which I should update again with new
>   findings when I sort out my thoughts.
>
> When the pipe character is used in a title tag, Google treats the tag
>   as a keyword list. This does not work for other characters- it is a
>   relatively new effect following a trend. If the domain name, either
>   with or without the TLD, appears at the end of the list Google takes
>   it as a branding signal and will place example.com : at the beginning
>   of the title tag and remove the keyword from the end of the title tag.

While there is not a direct match, it appears that Google is picking up the branding signal and doing what is advertised.

From this answer: [Does changing company/brand name in title have SEO issues?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96824/does-changing-company-brand-name-in-title-have-seo-issues/96831#96831)

> The pipe character (|) indicates a semantic cluster. A semantic
>   cluster is a sub-section of text that is to be semantically analyzed
>   by itself.
>
> Google is specifically looking for a brand in the last section. If
>   your brand is recognized as a brand within the brand ontology such as
>   Kellogg, Mars, Coke Cola, etc., Google will primarily defer to the
>   ontology. If your brand does not exist in the brand ontology (or even
>   if it does), Google will specifically look at the terms within the
>   brand and the domain name.

This is the first case where I have seen Google picking up branding signals from a semantic cluster that is not the last one.

Whenever people use the pipe character within the title tag, they should really know what is going on. In your case, Google is doing what is advertised and there is no surprise here.

I suggest reading the two linked answers for specific information. It will be a trivial edit of the title tag to change this effect.

If you want to avoid this form of branding altogether, you can avoid using pipes with a title such as this:

> Web Design & Web Development by Ixeun Software Solutions - Batticaloa

Comment: Thanks for making time to answer my question. Could you please tell me what i am did now is correct for SEO or not please ?

Comment: @Jerushan I went to your home page, viewed the source, and I do not see a difference. While I am not sure what your goal is with the pipes, I would avoid them if you do not want the `example.com:` to appear. Perhaps something like, `Web Design & Web Development by Ixeun Software Solutions - Batticaloa` Cheers!!

Comment: Corrected and Removed Pipes from my Title tags - thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a 'feature' that we can't actively control yet as webmasters.

I have been unable to find any resource that states why Google decides to append/prepend the sitename or how you can add/remove this when it's unwanted for your site.

What is the reason that you want the name to be removed?