# My site title or blogpost title, which should be h1?

Tags: seo, title, h1

I'm in the process of coding my personal website. After looking at some articles to help me understand how SEO works, I learned that keywords need to be in H1s.

It sounds logical for my blog post titles to be H1s, but what about my name? (The part of my website in the top left that users click to go back home)

I was thinking; since it's my personal blog and I really want it to come up when people search for it, could I wrap my name in an H2 or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The blog post title should be H1, as it's the most important piece of text on the page. You'll mostly want people to be able to find you through that one title.

You can ofcourse add your name as the author to the blog post itself. However, I wouldn't make a H2 of it, because you mostly want to be found on the content of that blog post instead of your name. Make sure to add the rel=”author” with your name in it to also be found on your own name.

If you need any more help, just answer on this answer.

Comment: The site title would be good as an H1 on the home page (only).    You are correct that other pages should have their own title as the most prominent text on the page.

Comment: I'm a little out of the loop at the moment on best practice but I'd have thought you'd have h1 as subordinate to head and h1 as subordinate to article and that for SEO/accessibility any tool that was HTML5 aware would be more than up to recognising what's page chrome and what's the article. None of this will matter for off-site but on-site when an SE is deciding the most relevant content they're going to be looking at the <article> level (assuming your site is properly marked up). If Google/Bing/etc/ don't yet know how to recognise content from boilerplate I'll eat my hat.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend that the h1 tag be an expansion of the title. The title is limited by the number of characters (45-55 or as long as 65) to be effective as a SERP link while the h1 does not have the same limitation. For this reason, when I write a title tag, I keep it pithy and word it in such a way that the h1 would be a longer version of the title tag.

As for branding your blog, you can brand in the title using either the `:` or `|` character in the title tag, however, what works best is schema mark-up. I would suggest using both if you can. I do not use `:` or `|` in my title tags at all. The reason is simple. I need the space for the title. I do use mark-up and branding works fine for me. But then again, my sites are businesses and not a blog per se' though there are blog style posts on the site.

Here is some of my answers explaining `:` and `|`.

[Does changing company/brand name in title have SEO issues?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96824/does-changing-company-brand-name-in-title-have-seo-issues/96831#96831)

[Site URL being displayed before TITLE on SERP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/site-url-being-displayed-before-title-on-serp/78025#78025)

This may be confusing, however, in reality it is really simple.

Basically, you would create your title as something like this. "How to change a faucet | example.com" This would create a SERP link as "Example: How to change a faucet." You can also use "How to change a faucet - example.com" which will taken as is to produce a SERP link as "How to change a faucet - example.com" and still take up example.com as branding. I suggest using the first example.

As far as branding the blog, you can use the Schema Blog mark-up found here https://schema.org/Blog.

If you are an organization, and I mention this just in case it applies, you can use Schema Organization found here https://schema.org/Organization. There are other types of organizations listed toward the bottom of the page.